# How do I execute a JS script when opening a specific sub page in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, mobile, multipage

I have a multipage setup using jQuery Mobile. The script will get a canvas width and height, but the canvas is not visible when the script gets executed.

How do I execute a script only when opening the subpage?

Comment: @mus please don't use code markup for anything which isn't code.

Comment: take a look at http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-show or http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/, depending on which version of jQuery Mobile you're using.